# Extending lists with the same value on Python

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I am very new to python, and I was trying to create a graph with matplotlib. I could create the first line with no problem, I defined 2 lists with x and y values that had the same length. For the second line, I was trying to plot a graph that displays the maximum y value of the first line for each x. My question is, do I have to explicitly write max(y1) x amount of times, or is there a way to automate the process?

```
x1 = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]

y1 = [36.37, 36.18, 36.31, 36.24, 36.31, 36.37, 36.18, 36.43, 36.12, 36.24, 36.06, 36.31, 36.12, 36.49, 36.74, 36.74]

plt.plot(x1, y1, color='black', marker='o', markerfacecolor='black', markersize='10', label='line1')

# I could just write x1 but this was a little easier for me to structure my code
x2 = x1

# Do I have to write [max(y1), max(y1), max(y1) ..., max(y1)] here or can I make a list with fewer items to represent one line (in this case y=36.74)
y2 = [max(y1)]

plt.plot(x2, y2, color='#30C3BF', linestyle='dashed', label='line2')
```

Comment: Might be worth checking out the `axhline` method.  I.e. draw a horizontal line spanning the whole x axis

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply lists.

```
y2 = [max(y1)] * len(y1)
```

results in a single list of the same length as y1 with all values set to the maximum in y1